# Ellipsis for long text

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg

I have found a few examples out there but having a hard time getting any to work, if anyone had a clearer or some insight would be much appreciated.

```
var wrap = function() {
var self = d3.select(this),
textLength = self.node().getComputedTextLength(),
text = self.text();
while (textLength > (50) && text.length > 0) {
text = text.slice(0, -1);
self.text(text + '...');
textLength = self.node().getComputedTextLength();
}
};



const y = d3.scaleBand()
.range([height, 0], .1)
.domain(data.map(function (d) {
return d.name; <----- wrap need to somehow attach to this
})
);
```

Comment: why do you want this `wrap` in a `domain` of a `scaleX`?

Answer (score 6):

The problem with your approach, whatever you're trying to do, is that `getComputedTextLength()` doesn't work on *imaginary* elements, or on data not attached to an element... it works only in a real SVG element, present on the SVG.

However, since you want to pass that array of strings to the domain of a band scale, which we typically set *before* the elements are rendered, it seems to me that you want to trim long strings beforehand.

If that's correct, a possible approach is rendering a temporary element, just to get its computed text length, trimming it, creating a new string and discarding the temporary element.

So, supposing we have this data array:

```
var data = ["A very long long long text here",
    "another very very long piece of text in this string",
    "finally, here we have another very big string"
];
```

We can use a modified version of your wrap function to trim the strings. Here is a demo, check the console:

```js
var data = ["A very long long long text here",
  "another very very long piece of text in this string",
  "finally, here we have another very big string"
];

var svg = d3.select("svg");

data.forEach(wrap);

function wrap(d, i, arr) {
  var self = svg.append("text")
    .text(d);
  var textLength = self.node().getComputedTextLength();
  while (textLength > 50 && d.length > 0) {
    arr[i] = arr[i].slice(0, -1);
    self.text(arr[i] + '...');
    textLength = self.node().getComputedTextLength();
  }
  arr[i] += "...";
  self.remove();
}

console.log(data)
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v5.min.js"></script>
<svg></svg>
```

As this uses real elements, things like font size matter. For instance, compare the result above with the result below, using another font and font size:

```js
var data = ["A very long long long text here",
  "another very very long piece of text in this string",
  "finally, here we have another very big string"
];

var svg = d3.select("svg");

data.forEach(wrap);

function wrap(d, i, arr) {
  var self = svg.append("text")
    .text(d);
  var textLength = self.node().getComputedTextLength();
  while (textLength > 50 && d.length > 0) {
    arr[i] = arr[i].slice(0, -1);
    self.text(arr[i] + '...');
    textLength = self.node().getComputedTextLength();
  }
  arr[i] += "...";
  self.remove();
}

console.log(data)
```

```css
text {
  font-size: 8px;
  font-family: "Arial Narrow";
}
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v5.min.js"></script>
<svg></svg>
```

However, have in mind that `getComputedTextLength()` apparently ignores things like `letter-spacing`, as you can see here: [Compute textlength with letter-spacing with D3.js](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37300187/5768908)